# Get directory name with grep and remove it

Tags: bash, shell, grep

please is there any simple way how can I get **NAME** output only from lines, where DATE < 5 days ago and then call other command called rm on these lines with NAME as argument?

I have the following output from mega-ls path/ -l (mega.nz) command:

```
FLAGS VERS    SIZE            DATE       NAME
d---    -          - 06Feb2020 05:00:01 bk_20200206050000
d---    -          - 07Feb2020 05:00:01 bk_20200207050000
d---    -          - 08Feb2020 05:00:01 bk_20200208050000
d---    -          - 09Feb2020 05:00:01 bk_20200209050000
d---    -          - 10Feb2020 05:00:01 bk_20200210050000
d---    -          - 11Feb2020 05:00:01 bk_20200211050000
```

I tried grep, sort and other ways e.g. **mega-ls path/ -l | head -n 5** but I don't know how to search these lines based on the date.

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Use the `find` command.

Comment: To add to @Barmar 's comment, it sounds like you just want something like `find path -type f  -mtime 5 -delete`  (Replace -delete with -print before you execute this)

Comment: `mega-ls` or `megals` uses an api of mega.nz website.

Comment: Which files do you want to delete?

Comment: @cyrus I want to remove all directories (NAME from the above output) which were created more than five days ago.

Comment: Do a `find`, as has been suggested before, but delete it with `-exec rm -rf {} \;`.  For a dry run, prefix the `rm` by `echo`.

Comment: I tried to do it with find but without result. E.g. `find $(mega-ls /path/ -l) -mtime +1`
returns following: 

`find: ‘d---’: No such file or directory
find: ‘-’: No such file or directory
find: ‘-’: No such file or directory
find: ‘10Feb2020’: No such file or directory
find: ‘05:00:01’: No such file or directory
find: ‘bk_20200210050000’: No such file or directory`

what is absolutely fine. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I try find simple way for you request ;)

```
mega-ls path/ -l | head -n 5 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f6 | grep -v -e '^$' | grep '^bk_20200206.*' | xargs rm -f
```

Part 1 : This is you command (returned folders list by extra data)

> mega-ls path/ -l | head -n 5

Part 2 : Try to remove extra space in your part 1 result

> tr -s ' '

Part 3 : Try to use cut command to delimit result part 2 and return Name Folders column

> cut -d ' ' -f6

Part 4 : Try to remove Empty lines from result part 3 (result of header line)

> grep -v -e '^$'

Part 5 : This your request for search folders name by date yyyymmdd format example : 20200206 (replace 20200206 to your real date need)

> grep '^bk_20200206.*'

Part 6 : **(Very Important!!) If you need to delete result folders use this part (Very Important!!)**

> xargs rm -f

Best Regards

Comment: Your `cut` would not work if there are spaces in the filename, as this would then only pick the first part of the file name.

Comment: In `grep`, the `.*` at the end of the pattern is redundant, unless you use the -o flag.